# binding and unbinding function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

1) When `#pin_point` is on hover, I set two absolute positioned images to fadeToggle so that it changes with fade effect:

```
$("#pin_point").hover(function  hoverhandler() {
    $("#pin_point img").fadeToggle('medium');
});
```

2) When `#pin_point` is clicked, I set pin_point `img` to swap to "ex.png":

```
$("#pin_point").click(function() {
    $("#pin_point img").attr('src','images/ex.png');
});
```

3) When `#pin_point` is clicked I also unbind the hover function in #1(above).

*Question*: If I want to bind the function when #pin_point is clicked again,
what should I do? below is the code I have, and I'm having a hard time figuring out. 
can anyone help?

```
$("#pin_point").click(function() {
    $('#pin_point').unbind('hover', hoverhandler);
    $("#pin_point img").attr('src','images/ex.png');
    $('#pin_point').bind('hover', hoverhandler);
});
```

Comment: Can you maybe explain what it is that you want to happen, vs. how to solve your particular problem?

Comment: Can you tell what exactly you are trying to do ?

Comment: i'm trying to show #pin_point img instead of 'image/ex.png' when #pin_point is clicked again. clear enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hover` is a short hand event. Instead unbind `mousenter` and `mouseleave`. Also attach a state information to the element to get the alternate effect on each click.

```
function hoverhandler() {
    $("img", this).stop(true, true).fadeToggle('medium');
}
$("#pin_point").hover(hoverhandler);

$("#pin_point").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        enableHover = $this.data('enableHover'), //get the current state
        method = "bind"; //default mathod to bind

    if (!enableHover) {  //if alternate click to disable
         method = "unbind"; //change the method
    } 

    $this[method]('mouseenter mouseleave', hoverhandler); //apply the method
    $this.find("img").prop('src', 'http://placehold.it/40x40');
    $this.data('enableHover', !enableHover);//save the state in the element to toggle between each click

});
```

You can use `on` and `off` if you are using jquery version >= 1.7.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bk3Jr/)**

Comment: when the div is clicked again it doesn't change back to 50X50. instead, it changes to 40X40, which is the img attr from the src. can you show me how to fix this matter?

Comment: @KcLee you can add that part to switch the image in the else part... See this http://jsfiddle.net/T3ct5/

Comment: @KcLee Is that what you asked for?

Comment: <div id="pin_point" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fluid"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30"  style="position:absolute;" id="pin" alt=""/><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="position:absolute;display:none;" id="pin_two" alt=""/></div>     in this case, image doesn't change back to 30X30 on second click

Answer (score 0):

What you're passing to `.hover` is a [named function expression](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/). Its name is not supposed to be available to other code, you have to make it a function declaration:

```
function hoverhandler() {
    $("#pin_point img").fadeToggle('medium');
}
$("#pin_point").hover(hoverhandler);
```

According to the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

> Calling `$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` is shorthand for:
>
> `$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn).mouseleave( handlerOut );`

So you can unbind with

```
$("#pin_point").off('mouseenter'. hoverhandler).off('mouseleave', hoverhandler );
```

Comment: I tried, and it doesn't work. when #pin_point is clicked for the second time. it doesn't change back to #pin_point img in (step1)

Comment: I just found something interesting in the docs, answer updated. Please try now.